# How do we download files in a particular commit Id in Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

Basically we need to share the source code files changed as a part of a commitId from remote repo to another person with the appropriate folder structure in gitlab.
In Github there is an API which downloads the files changed as a part of a particular commit id.

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/archive/<commitId>.zip
```

The reason we need this is because multiple teams working on a project has different source control like TFS and Git and the files needs to be merged across teams (from GIT to TFS).

Tried creating git bundle to share files but most of the times it gives an error
"fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.".

Also tried creating patch but it did not solve the problem. Is there a way to achieve this by git bundle and git patch for a specific commit id from remote ?

Please help since manually keeping track of the changed files is not the way we want to go ahead with as it would be error prone and cumbersome.

Comment: You fail to give specifics.  Exactly how are you trying to use `bundle` that is giving you the error?    Creating a bundle or a patch is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks William. I tried creating bundle as mentioned below - git bundle create <bundlename>.bundle <commitId> . Could you please help me with creating bundle from the remote repository based on the commit Id.

Comment: You create the bundle locally.  Just fetch the commit that you want from the remote first.